# Put javascript alert in Laravel model - Not able to alert message from Laravel Model

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, model, alert

I want to alert a invalid message to the user from Laravel Model, I wrote the code but its not alerting. This piece of code works perfectly in simple PHP with wamp but this does not work with Laravel Model.

I Know this can be done using Ajax response and show the message in actual JS file instead of Model/Controller file but I want to know if there is a way to alert a JavaScript from Model itself instead of again AJAX call.

following is the function in my Model PHP where I am trying to alert a message:

```
public static function Login_Authenticator($request)
{
    if($ldapconn)
    {
        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass) or  die("<script>alert('Invalid Credentials');</script>");
    }

}
```

Comment: You should get the message in the controller and accordingly redirect or show user invalid message

Comment: @urfusion Yes I am getting the response in the Controller.
 How can I ALERT a message in Controller/Model? Do I have to do it in finally JavaScript itself? I do not want to do in JavaScript, I am trying to do in Model/Controller.

Comment: Normally we redirect to view with error message like `return Redirect('/user/forgotpassword')
                                ->with('fail', 'Missing required information, please request again.');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think die will work here try echo instead of die. Although, I feel this is bad practice because php should be used at the server side only. Try to add javascript in the view itself.

Comment: Ya sure but still I am curious to find if there is a way to alert a message from Controller/Model. I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that you are getting the response in the controller then you should put a condition and redirect to view with an error message.

```
if (Your_condition) {
    return Redirect('/user/forgotpassword')
               ->with('fail', 'Missing required information, please request again.');
}
```